# Two-Way Communication Between HTML in .Net WebBrowser and WinForms application

Tags: c#, javascript, interop, browser, com-interop

When using `WebBrowser` control I would like to pass an object from javascript code to C#.

Solution is known - using `ObjectForScripting` property of `WebBrowser` and invoking methods from javascript code using `window.external`.

I know how to do that, but I would like to create object with given type in javascript and pass it to C# without using `object` or `dynamic`. Example:

I would like to call from JS this method in C#:

```
public void Test(Foo foo)
{
    //do something
}
```

Where `Foo` is:

```
[ComVisible(true)]
public class Foo
{
    public string Bar;
}
```

I know how to call those methods:

```
public void Test2(object foo)
{
    //do something
}

public void Test3(dynamic foo)
{
    //do something
}
```

but I would like to use the first one - `Test(Foo foo)`

What should I do to make it possible to pass object of class `Foo` from JS to C# or how to cast JS object on the fly to C# `Foo` object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found at least **two solutions**.

**First**, pretty obvious, is what Sheng Jiang suggested. You need to create a separate class library with those types:

```
[ComVisible(true)]
public interface IFoo
{
    string Bar { get; set; }
}

[ComVisible(true)]
public class Foo : IFoo
{
    public string Bar { get; set; }
}
```

This type library must be registered (Project/Properties/Build/Register for COM interop). Those types, especially interfaces, should be used in methods in exe which has the `WebBrowser` control. For example:

```
public string Bar(IFoo foo)
{
    return foo.Bar;
}

public IFoo Bar2()
{
    return new Foo() { Bar = "asdf" };
}
```

Now we can use those types in javascript:

```
var foo = new ActiveXObject("ClassLibrary1.Foo");
foo.Bar = "qwer";
alert(external.Bar(x));
var fooFromExternal = external.Bar2();
alert(fooFromExternal);
alert(external.Bar(fooFromExternal));
```

Unfortunately the **class library has to be registered** and you will get an **ActiveX warning** from IE.

**Second** solution is to not create class library, instead of leaving those types in the app exe. We still need interface `IFoo` if we want to pass objects from javascript to C#. And we need methods to create objects on the C# side for javascript:

```
public IFoo CreateFoo()
{
    return new Foo() { Bar = "asdf" };
}

public string Bar(IFoo foo)
{
    return foo.Bar;
}
```

Javascript usage:

```
var foo = external.CreateFoo();
alert(foo.Bar);
foo.Bar = "qwer";
alert(external.Bar(foo));
```

We **don't need to register anything for COM interop** and there will be **no ActiveX warning** from IE.

Answer (score 1):

The type system is weaker in jscript, so you can't have early binding classes. I suggest you to [make your class automatable and register your project's type library for late binding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1278495/c-implement-late-binding-for-native-code) so it can be called in jscript via new ActiveXObject.